Why are special characters get sent wrong when uploading via blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload plugin?
blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload plugin worked just fine. My app didn't have to use the original file name for uploading files. Now it is required that the original file name also gets uploaded and stored correctly in the web app.
The upload is done via json format.
      $(function () {
          $('#fileupload21').fileupload({
              dataType: 'json',
              sequentialUploads: true,
              singleFileUploads: false,
              limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
              add: function(e, data) {
                  $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    console.log('Added file: ' + file.name);
                  });
                  ...
                  data.submit();
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              },
              progressall: function (e, data) {
              },
              start: function (e, data) {
              }, 
              done: function (e, data) {
                  $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                     ... access file.origname or file.newname
                  });
              }
          });
      });

In the add callback I added a console logging and I see that the special characters are correctly displayed. So the widget gets the special characters correctly. But I guess with the data.submit() they get altered.
When I log the retrieved orig filenames on the serverside, special characters like ä ö ü are not properly displayed and get lost.
How to solve this?

Does it work if you just use the default add instead of overriding it with your own?

As far as I can tell from the documentation, it should send the filenames. If you look at the body in DevTools, are the filenames there correct?
